# Do one time action after logging in

Tags: 7

I need to add a Javascript file only once immediately after logging in - which will open another URL in a new window.

Without using _SESSION what'll be the right place to add drupal_add_js function only once after logging in?

Is there a hook which is called in the very first logged-in page?

Answer (score 0):

Add the JS file inside the implementation of [`hook_user_login()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7).
Function docs:

> The user just logged in.
>   Parameters
>
> `$edit`: The array of form values submitted by the user.
>
> `$account`: The user object on which the operation was just performed.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Can you paste the code by editing the question on what you've tried?

Comment: I've placed this code: 
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . "/newwindow.js", 'file');
 
}

Comment: Same code if I place in hook_init then it works.